# Rails mailer errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, actionmailer, mailer

This is my mailder

```
def registration_confirmation(user)
            @user = user
            delivery_options = { user_name: "#{user.name}",
                                  password: "#{user.password}",
                                   address: "#{user.to}" }

            mail(        to: "#{user.name} <#{user.to}>", 
                       from: "#{user.from}", 
                    subject: "Registered",
    delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
end
```

and this is my configs

```
development:
  :address: smtp.gmail.com
  :port: 587
  :authentication: plain
  :enable_starttls_auto: true
  :openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```

give this error

> 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

how i fix it?

Comment: Just confirming that you have provided your username and password ?

Answer (score -1):

If you specified gmail credential properly like this :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
                  :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
                  :port           => 587,
                  :authentication => :plain,
                  :user_name      => "username@gmail.com",
                  :password       => "gmail password",
                  :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
}
```

Then might be issue is from your authorization problem at gmail end. Go through this link https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and allow authentication. and you are done. More details here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257